# Confusion about a question regarding objective functions for an unbounded feasible region.

Tags: functions, inequality, optimization, linear-programming

I'm trying to teach myself some linear programming to help a friend with the course. I did maths in college so I felt like I could help. ( also wanted to learn it anyway for my own sake to upskill).
He showed me a question recently that confused me as it seems to be just the same answer twice. It goes as follows

We have the constraints

$$-2x+4y\leq10$$
$$-4x+2y\leq10$$

This will of course lead to an unbounded feasible region. Verified by inputting the constraint equations into desmos. [image]

The question then says 1) we have an objective function $$z=-2x+2y$$ 2) we have an objective function $$z=2x-2y$$.

In both instances it asks to comment on how each is influenced by the constraints, but in both instances the feasible region of course remains unbounded so originally I thought the answer for both is just that there are infinite solutions and so we can't figure out how to maximize it as we don't know all the corner points.

I feel after giving it some consideration that perhaps the case is that we must consider how it will act in each of the for quadrants.

for 1) $x\leq0, y\geq0$ would mean we have three corner points $$(0,25)(-25,0)(-16.67,16.67)$$ the third of which maximizes the objective function.

$x<0,y<0$ would mean we have some point on the line $2y-4x=100 \Rightarrow y=\tfrac{100+4x}{2}$. Inputting this into $$z=-2x+2y$$ gives $$z=-2x+\tfrac{4x+100}{2}=\tfrac{-4x+4x+100}{2}=50$$

$x>0, y>0$ would mean that any corner point would be on the line $-2x+4y=100\Rightarrow y=\tfrac{100+2x}{4}$ Inputting this into $$z=-2x+2y$$ gives $$z=-2x+\tfrac{2x+100}{4}=\tfrac{-8x+2x+100}{4}=\tfrac{6x+100}{4}$$ but as x goes to infinity the region where this function maximizes must be somewhere here as if we were in the other finalquadrant we'd have ....

$x>0, y<0$ and both go to infinity then $-2x$ is infinite negative and $2y$ is infinite negative so this corner point would minimize the function.

Then for the other other objective function we investigate it in the same way.

Does this seem like the right approach ?

Many thanks in advance for anyone who's kind enough to clear up my confusion.

Comment: It’s usual in linear programming to have the assumption that $x>9, y>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same graph, but with a smaller scale.

[image]

Next I've drawn in the objective function at level $z=0$. The equation is $0=-2x+2y\Rightarrow y=x$. This is the bisector. At the objective function the $-2x$ become positive if the x-values are negative. And $2y$ is positive for positive y-values. Therefore we push the objective function left upward until we reach the least feasible point to maximize the objective function. This is the intersection of the two constraints. A check with a calculator confirms the result, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=maximize+-2x%2B2y%2C+-2x%2B4y%5Cleq+10%2C+-4x%2B2y%5Cleq+10).

[image]

Comment: Ah ok I see the reasoning behind that one. Would I be right in saying that for the objective function $$z=2x-2y$$, that as 2x is positive when x is positive and as -2y is positive when y is negative that then there are infinite solutions for this function as the region which should maximise this function is in the 4th quadrant where x is positive, y negative and this region is unbounded . Therefore it's impossible to check the corner points ?

Comment: @JamieOM That's right. You would push the objective function at level $z=0$ parallelt right downward, where no bound exists.

Comment: Thanks callculus , I understand it now :)

Comment: @JamieOM You're welcome.